# What command is needed to clear the terminal in cern's root?

Tags: terminal, root-framework

I have just started using cern's ROOT and couldn't find a command to clear the terminal. The [beginner's manual](https://root.cern.ch/root/htmldoc/guides/primer/ROOTPrimer.html#root-basics) and the [user guide](https://root.cern.ch/root/htmldoc/guides/users-guide/ROOTUsersGuide.html) don't seem to mention anything about a command similar to clear in bash.

To be clear, what needs to be typed after `root[number]` prompt so that the console screen clears out and root keeps running?

Comment: I'm not aware of a clear in the root prompt. but to be sure you'll probably need to ask on the root forum (forum.root.ch) and maybe request it as a feature there.

Comment: Personally I use system("clear") on Linux and system("cls") on Windows. (Yeah it's stupid.

Comment: @MaryChang question is regarding cern's ROOT

Comment: Yeah, I type them into ROOT's prompt. It does the "clearing the entire screen" as advertised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @MaryChang
`.!clear`

P.S.: `.!cls` for windows; just `clear` or `cls` on root prompt doesn't work (as of ROOT ver 6.16/00)